# How to alter print behavior for an object in python

Tags: python

I have my unique class I created and i wish to control the output of some flow..e.g:

```
obj = MyObject()
print obj
```

so instead of what python does, I want to alter the output. 
how do I do such a thing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change the `__str__` method

```
class MyObject(object):
    def __str__(self):
        return 'foo'


>>> print MyObject()
foo
```

Comment: thanks. fits perfectly my solution just one small fix: in order to use the alternative __str__ implementation I had to use print str(obj), instead of print obj

Comment: @e-r-a-n No you don't need that... what happens when you don't use it?

Comment: sorry. my mistake. It didnt worked as expected the first time I tried but now it appears to work well without any modifications at the `print` section

Answer (score 8):

You can override `__str__` and `__repr__`.